# ¿Cómo hacer para que el resultado sean solo dos decimales en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, formato

Diseñe un algoritmo para convertir una cantidad en
bolívares (can_bs) en dólares, asumiendo que la unidad cambiaría es un
dato proporcionado (tasa).

```
can_bs=int(input("Indique la cantidad en bolivares a cambiar: "))

tasa=int(input("Indique la tasa $ del día: "))

resultado= can_bs / tasa

print("la cantidad en $ es: "+str (resultado) + " $")
```

---

```
Indique la cantidad en bolivares a cambiar: 1000000

Indique la tasa $ del día: 310000

la cantidad en $ es: 3.225806451612903 $
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una solución posible pasa por redondear el resultado a 2 decimales con la función round().

```
    can_bs=int(input("Indique la cantidad en bolivares a cambiar: "))

    tasa=int(input("Indique la tasa $ del día: "))

    resultado= can_bs / tasa
    c=round(resultado, 2)

    print("la cantidad en $ es: "+str (c) + " $")
```

Comment: Excelente pokeP, me resultó muy útil. Gracias!!!

Comment: @NoelTejeda Como eres nuevo probablemente no lo sepas, pero la mejor forma de dar las gracias en StackOverflow es marcando la respuesta que consideres mejor para tu pregunta como "respuesta correcta" y por qué no, dar votos positivos a aqueĺlas respuestas que lo merezcan.

Answer (score 2):

Si no quieres usar round para evitar modificar el valor, te recomiendo que uses el método [format](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp) de str:

```
can_bs = int(input("Indique la cantidad en bolivares a cambiar: "))
tasa = int(input("Indique la tasa $ del día: "))
resultado = can_bs / tasa

# :.2f indica que debe mostrar un float con 2 decimales y cualquier parte entera
formatted = "La cantidad en $ es: {:.2f}".format(resultado)
print(formatted)
```

Answer (score 0):

para redondear puedes usar la funcion `round(resultado)` round tambien recibe un parametro en el cual le puedes limitar la cantidad de decimales que quieres que entregue, se puede hacer de esta forma `round(resultado,2)`  en este caso te entregaria tu resultado y dos decimales.

```
print(round(num))
print(round(num,2))

resultado:
24
23.67
```

espero te pueda servir.

Answer (score 0):

```
can_bs = int(input("Indique la cantidad en bolivares a cambiar: "))
tasa = int(input("Indique la tasa $ del día: "))
#round() es la función mas socorrida para indicar el número de decimales que deseamos
resultado =round((can_bs / tasa),2) #Con dígito después de la coma,(2) estamos indicando el número de decimales que deseamos
print("Al cambio debo recibir la cantidad de ",resultado,"(USA$)dólares")
```